# Flatten Map of List of Objects in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I have the following variable structure as an input in Terraform:

```
variable "environments" {
  type = map(
    list(
      object(
        {
          env_name        = string,
          project_id      = string,
          grant_sa_access = optional(bool),
        }
      )
    )
  )
}
```

I'm attempting to flatten it like this:

```
  env_data_list = flatten([
    for github_repository_name, env_list in var.environments : [
      for env in env_list : {
        github_repository_name = github_repository_name,
        env_name               = env.env_name,
        project_id             = env.project_id,
        grant_sa_access        = (env.grant_sa_access == null) ? false : env.grant_sa_access,
      }
    ]
  ])
```

Terraform seems to be unable to recognize the property names of the object while looping through the `env_list`. I've found several examples of people looping through basic types (i.e. strings) like this and flattening them, but never `object`s, so I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? Any errors? Wrong result? If yes, what is expected outcome?

Comment: The code shows errors for being able to retrieve any variables off of `env`. i.e. `env.env_name` shows as an error in the IDE. However when I run the script, it actually shows as an error when I try to use, and get variables off of `env_data_list`. I'm expecting that `env_data_list` is a list({ env_name=string, github_repository_name=string, project_id=string, grant_sa_access=bool }), but I can't access any of the data on each list item in a resource for_each without it throwing an error.